# Get value from array in JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

Let's say we have this json in our database table. I want to select value from tags. I already know how to get an array from this data but I don't know how to access array members. The question would be how do I get the first value from the array? Is there a function for this task?

```
{
    "info": {
        "type": 1,
        "address": {
            "town": "Bristol",
            "county": "Avon",
            "country": "England"
        },
        "tags": ["Sport", "Water polo"]
    },
    "type": "Basic"
}
```

Query I already have:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(MyTable.Data, '$.info.tags')
FROM MyTable
```

This returns me:

```
["Sport", "Water polo"]
```

How do I get

```
Sport
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns an object or array. You need [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to return a scalar value, eg :

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(Data, '$.info.tags[0]')
from MyTable
```

Check the section [Compare JSON_VALUE and JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/validate-query-and-change-json-data-with-built-in-functions-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#JSONCompare) in the docs for more examples